# file is encrypted or is not a database message when application Become Active

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have random case of not able to access the sqlite database from my iPad app. I have used FMDatabase to access sqlite database and I have not enable DataProtection in My Provisioning profile.Also sqlite version is 3. This happens with passcode enabled devices. when the device goes to sleep while my app is in foreground this error comes randomly when user enter the passcode. Once user successfully enter the passcode my app comes to foreground and suddenly database inaccessible with sqlite code 26: file is encrypted or is not a database

Can some one help me to solve this issue.

I have added one place it occurred

```
-(NSString*)getValueForSetting:(NSString*)settingName{
    __block NSString *settingValue ;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SettingValue FROM Settings where SettingName = '%@' ",settingName];
    FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:[DatabaseUtility getDBPath]];
    @try{
        [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *database) {
            FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:sql];
            if (![database hadError]) {
                if([results next]){
                    settingValue = [results stringForColumn:@"SettingValue"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Database error,get setting value %d: %@", [database lastErrorCode], [database lastErrorMessage]);
            }
            [results close];
        }];
    }
    @catch(NSException *exception){
        NSLog(@"0002,ERR,MemberDataAccess,getiPadDisplayName:(NSString*)memberID, %@",[exception description]);
    }
    @finally {
        [queue close];
    }

    return settingValue;
}
```

here I got the following out put

```
Database error,get setting value 26: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

**EDIT 1:**

I was able to isolated the issue occurring code snippet. In `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method
I'm calling following method. This method used to redirect the NSLogs to a file.

```
-(void) redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *customPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LogFiles"];

    NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:customPath])  
        [manager createDirectoryAtPath: customPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSLog(@" DeviceLogs Class : custom path: %@",customPath);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [GlobalSettingsSingelton setLocale:&dateFormat];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSString *todaysDate = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:today]];
    NSString *logFile = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Log_%@.txt",todaysDate];
    NSString *logPath = [customPath
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:logFile];

    freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

Some times after calling this method my DB file get Corrupted or encrypted and gives above mentioned error when try to access the DB. If I comment this line App works without an issue.

To isolate the issue I called two db access methods before the freopen() and after. The DB access method I added after that method gives `file is encrypted or is not a database` error while previous db access method runs without that issue.

I cant imagine the issue since NSLog redirection nothing to do with the DB file. How it comes encrypted or corrupted. Please some one explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I was able to find the reason for this finally. first [this](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) article helped me to get a clue about sqlite application corruption. It indicate one reason which I have suspect was related my problem.

```
We have seen cases where a file descriptor was open on a log file, then that file descriptor was
 closed and reopened on an SQLite database. Later, some other thread continued to write log 
information into the old file descriptor, not realizing that the log file had been closed already.
 But because the file descriptor had been reopened by SQLite, the information that was intended to 
go into the log file ended up overwriting parts of the SQLite database, leading to corruption of the 
database.
```

By writing sample application I was able to recreate this issue. For that I used two threads. one thread continuously call `redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder` method using a timer. Other thread used to run  some sql queries in a loop and add some NSLog entries withing that. After some time I got the `file is encrypted or is not a database` error message.

As the fix i removed `redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder` method call in the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method and keep it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method which guarantee the fix due to following reasons.

1. Log file is already closed when app beginning to run.
2. There is only one thread alive (Which is main the main thread).
3. Log file opening is sequential process.

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons to see this issue,
It might be your application is trying to open the DB twice or multiple times so that one thread is blocked by the other. Please check whether there are other places where they try to open the same DB instance simultaneously. 
Also, the DB file might have got corrupted somehow, this happens when you overwrite the app while debugging. Just delete the application, restart the phone and see. 
Anyway, don't you think its better to use Core Data instead of directly dealing with the DB, is it your requirement ?

Comment: I was able to find the reason and add a fix.